# bootstrap panel overlaps floats

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have a simple side panel that floats to the left and a main container that is a bootstrap "panel". The bootstrap panel's borders overlap into my side-panel.

[image]

http://fiddlesalad.com/jade/bootstrap-panel-float/

```css
aside { width: 100px; float: left; }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<aside>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</aside>
<div class="panel panel-default panel-group container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
</div>
```

How to make them separated so they don't overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either write your own css to give elements width and display settings or you learn the grid system.

Learn basic CSS and html before using a framework, it will save a lot of pain.

The grid is 100/12  = each row is 12 columns. The xs class is from 0 - up viewport sizes. You can change this to col-sm-X and it will be from 768px and up. Getbootstrap.com and many, many other sources on how to use the Bootstrap 3 grid.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-xs-3">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</aside>

    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also explain why exactly is what I wrote not working? Which CSS property of the ".panel" class in bootstrap is making it overlap its borders onto my aside? Because if I remove the panel, it works just as I expect it to - the aside floats to the left and the content floats to its right. It's just the adding the "panel" class that makes it overlap with the aside

Answer (score 0):

That's because aside's width is set to 100px. Put a proper width like so:

```
aside {
   width: 100%;
}

.panel-default {
   clear: both;
}
```